# Tracking mouse movement in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I wrote a basic program to get the mouse location on a canvas and it's freezing my computer each time I run it, can someone take a look please? Also if you know a better way to do this, that'd be great.

I decided to learn this language because I don't like JavaScript and I read it's ideal for Java/C++ guys so that's why I started this language.

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

CanvasElement canvas = document.querySelector('#myPaintCanvas');
CanvasRenderingContext2D context = canvas.getContext('2d');


void pencil(mouseX, mouseY){
print("This is from pencil method: MouseX: " + mouseX.toString() + " MouseY: " + mouseY.toString());
}


void mouseDragginStarts(moveX, moveY){
print("This is from mouseDragging: " + "mouseX: "+ moveX + " mouseY:" + moveX);
}

void main(){
//get a refrence to the canvas

//canvas.onClick.listen((e) {
canvas.onDrag.listen((e){
print("Got a click (${e.client.x-canvas.offsetLeft}, ${e.client.y-canvas.offsetTop})");
pencil(e.client.x-canvas.offsetLeft, e.client.y-canvas.offsetTop);


//while(canvas.onClick.listen(e) == true && canvas.onDrag.listen(e) == true){
while(canvas.onDrag == true){
  mouseDragginStarts(e.client.x, e.client.y);

  if(e==false){
    break;
  }
}

});



/*context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.lineWidth = 4;
//set the line color
context.strokeStyle = '#ff0000'; //red
context.stroke();*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
while(canvas.onDrag == true){ <== I wonder if it enters the loop, canvas.onDrag never becomes true
  mouseDragginStarts(e.client.x, e.client.y);

  if(e==false){ <== e never becomes false
    break;
  }
}
```

Your code doesn't make any sense. You should start over by explaining what you actually try to accomplish.

When you only want to track mouse movement then you just do

```dart
canvas.onMouseMove.listen((e) {
  // do something with mouse coordinates
  // e.client.x, e.client.y
});
```

Comment: My bad bro, it's just I don't really understand the docs for this. I was just trying to get the movements that my mouse does on a canvas.I thought I had to use canvas.onDrag because I thought I had to click and drag before I could actually track my movement. Sorry.

Comment: onMouseMove should be enough. You might also be interested in onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, onMouseOver. The method you pass to listen (onMouseMove, onMouseOver) is called for each little mouse movement (very often). But you won't need onDragXxxx events. You also have onMouseDown, onMouseUp (or onClick which in addition is fired when onMouseDown and onMouseUp occur on the same position)